# how to check iterator before dereferencing (C++)?

Tags: c++

I am using static analysis tool to find a bugs in my code.It shows the error before dereferencing u have to check your iterator is NULL or not.How can I check this? See the code below:

```
for(ClientThreadGroupList_t::iterator it = m_vecClientThreadGroup.begin(); it != m_vecClientThreadGroup.end(); it++) 
{
  nCount += (*it)->ConsoleList(pSocket); //error
}
```

Comment: `(*it) != NULL` or in C++11 `(*it) != nullptr`

Comment: Please pay attention to the question preview before posting to make sure the code is formatted correctly in the future.

Comment: Besides an `if` statement you can also use an assert.

Comment: @ddriver An assertion probably wouldn't silence a static analyser, though.

Comment: This sounds like a bad contract from the side of `ClientThreadGroupList`. I'd hate to have to check for `nullptr`...

Comment: What static analysis tool were you using? Cause I'm currently looking for that function...

Answer (score 5):

The check for iterator validity is already in your code:

```
it != m_vecClientThreadGroup.end()
```

Note that, in general, you can't check whether an iterator is valid or dereferencably; but, when you're iterating over a sequence, you know that the iterators will be dereferencable until you reach the end of the sequence.

Since your sequence apparently contains pointers, you might also need to check whether they are null before dereferencing:

```
if (*it) {
    nCount += (*it)->ConsoleList(pSocket);
}
```

Note that this will only check for null pointers; you can't in general check whether or not a non-null pointer actually points to a valid object.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(ClientThreadGroupList_t::iterator it = m_vecClientThreadGroup.begin(); it != m_vecClientThreadGroup.end(); it++) {
if (*it != 0)
   nCount += (*it)->ConsoleList(pSocket); //error    
}
```

m_vecClientThreadGroup.begin() returns NULL ptr as i suppose

and are you sure you want to use (*it)->ConsoleList(pSocket) instead of it->ConsoleList(pSocket)?

Comment: No, that's not how you check iterator validity. Comparison against `0` is most likely not defined for an iterator. The iterator itself is correctly checked against `end()`. What the OP is missing is the check of the pointer the iterator refers to.

Comment: just meant if (*it != 0)

Answer (score 1):

**A pointer can implicitly converted to Boolean type**, simply call `if(*it)` to test nullity of a pointer

```
for(ClientThreadGroupList_t::iterator it = m_vecClientThreadGroup.begin(); 
    it != m_vecClientThreadGroup.end(); ++it) 
//                                      ^^^^ // better practice
{
    if (*it)  // test if a pointer is null or not
    {
        nCount += (*it)->ConsoleList(pSocket);  
    }
}
```

Update from comment:

Looks like the issue is multiple threading issue, you need to provide **lock mechanism** to avoid another thread invalid your current iterators.

Comment: hi all, i tried this way but it is not fixed..it showing error in predefined of STL.. Pointer 'it._M_cur' returned from call to function..  may be NULL and may be dereferenced..   clientThreadgrouplist is a deque

Comment: yes it was used by multiple threads..i thing we cannot check the iterator like this...

Comment: You still can check like this, but you need to provide lock. Prevent actions which may invalid iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check it with an `if` condition :

```
for(ClientThreadGroupList_t::iterator it = m_vecClientThreadGroup.begin(); it != m_vecClientThreadGroup.end(); it++) 
{
    if ( (*it) != NULL ) // or in C++11 != nullptr
        nCount += (*it)->ConsoleList(pSocket); //error
}
```

It is the call to `ConsoleList` method on a `NULL` object who cause the error I suppose. Because, if there is no element in your `list`, `begin()` will be the same as `end()` and you will never enter in the loop.

For brevity you can do :

```
if ( *it ) // Implicit convertion here...
```